# I have an undefined value in row and column variable for setBoard function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

So, I am trying to create a minesweeper game using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. My problem here is that, when I call input (which stores a function), the result is that I get an undefined value in the setBoard function for my rows and columns variables.
However, the rows and columns variables in the getDimensions functions does not return an undefined value, and instead returns the proper value that the user inputs.

````
let dimensions;
let input = function getDimensions() {
    let rows, columns;

    rows = document.getElementById("boardRows").value; //The rows variable stores the number of rows that the user enters.
    columns = document.getElementById("boardColumns").value; //The columns variable stores the number of columns that the user enters.

    //This if-statement will run if there are: more than 30 rows, less than 4 rows, more than 30 columns, or less than 4 columns.
    if ((rows > 30) || (rows < 4) || (columns > 30) || (columns < 4)) {
        //An alert message is printed to the browser telling the user that the value(s) that they have entered are invalid.
        alert("ERROR! The number of rows are: " + rows + " and the number of columns are: " + columns + ". Please" +
            "enter your rows and columns between 4 and 40.");
    } else {
        dimensions = [rows, columns];
        alert(rows + " " + columns);
        return(dimensions);
    }

}

function setBoard() {
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let rows = input[0];
    let columns = input[1];
    alert("Here " + rows + " " + columns);
    canvas.height = columns * 20;
    canvas.width = rows * 20;
}```
````

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get currently? `cannot read property 'value' of null`, or something similar?

Comment: No, the error message that I get is:                                                                                         "Here  undefined undefined"                                                                                                 I am talking about the setBoard function. That's where I am getting the undefined values from.

Comment: `input` is a function, it's not an array, it doesn't have `[0]` or `[1]` properties

Comment: So, how can I extract the return values from the getDimensions function? The return values in that function are of type array.

Comment: Call the function instead, or reference the `dimensions` variable instead

Answer (score 0):

In your `setBoard()` function, you typed `let columns = input[1]`, which tries to access the second element of `input` assuming it is an array. If you meant to call the `input()` function with an argument `1`, you should write `let columns = input(1)`.

If you were trying to call `input()` and access the second element from the array it returns (the first element will have an index `0`), you could type `let columns = input()[1]`.